# Nodejs Response Data in Angular - duplicate array elements received

Tags: node.js, angular

I am receiving data from Nodejs in Angular. When the data is received in Angular, one of the array has duplicate elements.
e.g. if Node transmits an array of 2 elements, what is displayed in Angular table are 4 elements. The 2 elements sent by Nodejs are duplicated within the array to make it 4 . very weird. When I console.log in Node I can see the array with 2 elements. When I console.log in Angular the array length is shown as 2, but when the array is expanded, the length is shown as 4. Please see the attached screen shot of console.

**Angular Component ts file method**

```
onGetRequisitionToEdit(id){
    this.requisitionService.getRequisition(id)
      .subscribe(resData => {
        console.log('resData.shortlist.length', resData.shortlist.length);
        console.log('resData.shortlist', resData.shortlist);
        // pls see screenshot of console
        this.requisition = resData.requisition;
      
        // more code
    })
```

**Angular Service method**

```
  getRequisition(id: string) {
    return this.httpClient.get<{requisition: Requisition, interviews: Interview[], shortlist: Shortlist[], history: Syslog[]}>(this.reqUrl + '/get/' + id);
  }
```

**Node controller method**

```
exports.getRequisition = (req, res, next) => {
  requisitionService.getRequisition(req.params.id)
    .then(resData => {
      res.status(200).json(resData);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).json({
        message: "Server Error in fetching requisitions: " + err
      });
    });
}
```

**Node Controller Service**

```
async function getRequisition(id){
  const requisition = await Requisition.findById(id);
  if(!requisition) {
    throw 'Requisition not found';
  }

  let interviews;
  interviews = await Interview.find({reqnId: id}).collation({ locale: 'en'});
  if(!interviews) interviews = [];

  let shortlist;
  shortlist = await Shortlist.find({reqnId: id}).collation({ locale: 'en'});
  if(!shortlist) shortlist = [];
  console.log('shortlist', shortlist);
  ///////////// output: 2 elements

  let history;
  history = await Syslog.find({reqnId: id}).collation({ locale: 'en'});
  if(!history) history = [];

  const resData = {
    requisition: requisition,
    interviews: interviews,
    shortlist: shortlist,
    history: history
  }

  return resData;
}
```

Please help - where am I going wrong?

[image: console screenshot]

Comment: There is other (later) code that changes `this.shortList` in the service - the fact it shows two items but 4 when you click on it is because the console is async - it shows the two items and when you expand them it makes another (debugger) request to get information about that object.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum thanks.. indeed later in the code the shortlist array was changed. I had forgotten to remove that piece of code. Good way to learn that console is async.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to distinct the items in the backend if possible and if not you can use the `filter()` function. It's a JavaScript function also used in Typescript.